# Ajax doesn't return json if there is text in php file

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm pretty new to Jquery Ajax and sorry if that's a simple thing.

So my problem here is that I want to retrieve a json object from my php file, but it only works when I echo only one Json object like this :

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
$arr = array ('Lastname'=>'Doe','Firstname'=>'John','Age'=>109);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

When I want to echo another json or some text returned as json in my javascript file, I don't get anything back from the ajax call.

```
  <?php
// This code doesn't work
    header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    $arr = array ('Lastname'=>'Doe','Firstname'=>'John','Age'=>109);
    echo 'hi there';
    $json = 'Hello people';
    echo json_encode($json);
    echo json_encode($arr);
```

My ajax call is this :

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'test.php',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
```

So my final question is : what's wrong in my code, and what's not allowed in ajax call

Comment: Why not you using $.getJSON or in ajax dataType: json and from php use array_merge or array_push to collect all data as in array. The best approach is collect all array key value in one array and then just return to ajax. Use ajax success callback to deal with JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the output of this code

```php
// This code doesn't work
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
$arr = array ('Lastname'=>'Doe','Firstname'=>'John','Age'=>109);
echo 'hi there';
$json = 'Hello people';
echo json_encode($json);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Will be:

```php
hi there"Hello people"{"Lastname":"Doe","Firstname":"John","Age":109}
```

Which is **not valid JSON**

Correct way of responding with JSON is to use just **one** call to `json_encode`:

```php
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8')
$response = [
    'message' => 'hi there',
    'people' => [
        ['Lastname'=>'Doe', 'Firstname'=>'John', 'Age'=>109],
    ],
];
echo json_encode($response);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can only put one JSON object in a response. If you have more than one thing you want to send, just make an array:

```
echo json_encode([
    'user' => ['Lastname'=>'Doe', 'Firstname'=>'John', 'Age'=>109],
    'other' => 'some other stuff',
    'more' => ['even', 'more', 'suff'],
]);
```

You also don't want any extraneous output before or after the JSON, so remove this:

```
echo 'hi there';
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot merge two JSON encoded objects as this results in invalid JSON syntax.

What you can do is build a single array/object, encode into JSON and echo the resulting string.

The encoded string is the only output you can send back to the client.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send multiple JSON responses via single output. Use Websockets  for that or group responses into bag:

```
json_decode([$json, $arr])
```